# Stying a Leaflet LayerControl label using CSS?

Tags: leaflet

I want to be able to style the text on my layer control by adding a class to the HTML it produces. For example, as per [the tutorial](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/):

```
var baseMaps = {
    "OpenStreetMap": osm,
    "Mapbox Streets": streets,
    "Satellite": satellite
};
var layerControl = L.control.layers(baseMaps).addTo(map);
```

Produces:

```
<label>
   <span>
      <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_55" checked="checked" />
      <span> OpenStreetMap</span>
   </span>
</label>
...
```

Which looks like:

[image: Screenshot of a layer control]

I want the *individual names* to have a class - like this:

`<span class="MyClass"> OpenStreetMap</span>`

[The documentation](https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers) says:

> The layer names can contain HTML, which allows you to add additional styling to the items:

`{"<img src='my-layer-icon' /> <span class='my-layer-item'>My Layer</span>": myLayer}`

However, this gives the HTML an *additional* span. So the HTML looks like:

```
<label>
   <span>
      <input type="radio" class="leaflet-control-layers-selector" name="leaflet-base-layers_28
      <span> ⬅ Extra unwanted span
         <span class="checkable">OpenStreetMap</span>
      </span>
   </span>
</label>
```

The CSS I'm using ([Picnic](https://picnicss.com/documentation#radiobutton)) doesn't cope with this extra span and won't style it.  It uses:

`[type="radio"] + .checkable`

How do I get rid of the extra span?  (I suspect the answer is to try and fix the CSS upstream - but thought I'd see if there is a different way.)